# How to Implement Interfaces or Unions in Express-GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I am using `express-graphql` and I am trying to implement interfaces, like [here](https://atheros.ai/blog/graphql-interfaces-and-unions-how-to-design-graphql-schema) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088172/how-do-you-handle-an-array-of-multiple-types-ex-different-content-blocks-in-g). However, I do not know how to implement those, since the notation people use is totally different from what I am used to in nodejs.

In the second answer, for example, somebody wrote this:

```
type Query {
  blocks: [ ContentBlock! ]!
}

type Video implements ContentBlock {
  id: ID!
  url: String!
}

type Quote implements ContentBlock {
  id: ID!
  body: String!
  author: String
}

type Advertisement implements ContentBlock {
  id: ID!
  src: String!
  backgroundColor: String
}


interface ContentBlock {
  id: ID!
}
```

My own definitions in `express-graphql` look more like this however:

```
const Quote = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Quote",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    body: { type: GraphQLString },
    author: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});
```

Could somebody help me out here? I am also wondering where to find this information in general. I looked at the [documentation of express-graphql on github](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql) but I couldn't find anything explaining how to do interfaces or unions.

Comment: schema-first ve code-first ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396417/6124657

Comment: You're using https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type. You can just create a `GraphQLInterfaceType` or `GraphQLUnionType`.